# Set selected item for QComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I have a simple `QComboBox` widget, which has 2 values inside: `True` and `False`.
And I have a QString variable `currValue`, which is one of those values. I want to set my widget's current value with `currValue`.

I thought that solution is the following:
first lets initialize currValue;
`QString currValue = "False";`

```
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
combo->addItem("True");
combo->addItem("False");
combo->setCurrentIndex(combo->findData(currValue));
```

But it doesn't work.
Am I doing something wrong ?
And Why QComboBox has no member setCurrentItem() or smth like that ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You actually need to write it in the following way:

```
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
combo->addItem("True", "True");
combo->addItem("False", "False");
combo->setCurrentIndex(combo->findData("False"));
```

The problem in your implementation was that you did not set the items' *userData*, but only text. In the same time you tried to find item by its *userData* which was empty.
With the given implementation, I just use the second argument of `QComboBox::addItem(const QString &text, const QVariant &userData = QVariant()))` function that sets the item's *userData* (`QVariant`).

**UPDATE:**

The alternative way to find the combo box item is setting the specific role as the second argument for `QComboBox::findData()` function. If you don't want to explicitly set the user data, you can refer to the items texts with `Qt::DisplayRole` flag, i.e.:

```
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
combo->addItem("True");
combo->addItem("False");
combo->setCurrentIndex(combo->findData("False", Qt::DisplayRole)); // <- refers to the item text
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Another alternative could be using text based lookup function `QComboBox::findText()`:

```
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
combo->addItem("True");
combo->addItem("False");
combo->setCurrentIndex(combo->findText("False"));
```

Comment: Why ?! What is the meaning of 2 equal arguments ??

Comment: I see. But In this case I think that it is confusing that if I have just texts and I don't need data, I have to set also data when adding new items. I think there MUST be easier way to set selected, the text I have.

Comment: @KarenTsirunyan: well, if you don't want to set the user data, you can refer to the combo box items' texts. See another update of my answer.

Comment: I understand that you suggest real solutions, but as You can see there are a little bit weird, as I want to find the text, but I work with data. I just found out that `QComboBox` has also `findText()` method, which is the very thing I wanted to. :)

Comment: @KarenTsirunyan, I proposed three different ways to get the same result - you can use either of them.

Comment: Thank you, vahancho, for a well-written exploration of the ways to use a QComboBox. I was looking at the manual and thinking "I need to make a QVariant object, whatever that is... how do I store my object in that? Ooh, so it says here I need to write some kind of custom subclass of QVariant for user data? Just to populate a combobox? WTF?" - and then your examples showed me just how easy it really is. Now I just have all my data in an array, and pass the index as the userData, and life is delightfully easy for me. So, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I have got answer to my own question.

```
combo->setCurrentIndex(combo->findText(currValue));
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also call `setCurrentText()`